# Wagtail: Passing Django form to WagtailAdmin (Sidebar: Forms)

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a very interesting task.

- Wagtail Form with a FileField - For image upload (I guess this is not possible yet)

From the point that this is not possible yet in Wagtail I've tried another thing.

1. A Django Form (from this example [django form in wagtail](https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example)) that has actually a FileField.
2. Generate the link to uploaded image (let's say '/media/pics/image_example.jpg')
3. Somehow pass this link (a text field) to Wagtail Form and auto-submit it.

So at the end, we have the Form Submissions in WagtailAdmin that has a field with the direct url to the uploaded image.

But.. I don't really understand how this must work. Any ideas? Maybe there are better solutions for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a method as mentioned below

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):

    import random
    import string

    # random_str length will be 16 which will be combination of (4 digits + 4 characters + 4 digits + 4 characters)
    random_str =  "".join([random.choice(string.uppercase) for i in range(0,4)]) + "".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(0,4)]) + \
                    "".join([random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(0,4)]) + "".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(0,4)])

    # return string seperated by hyphen eg:
    random_str =  random_str[:4] + "-" + random_str[4:8] + "-" + random_str[8:12] + "-" + random_str[12:]
    filetype = filename.split(".")[-1].lower()
    filename = random_str +"." +  filetype
    path = "yourapp/uploads/" + str(datetime.datetime.now().year) + "/" + str(datetime.datetime.now().month) + "/" + str(datetime.datetime.now().day) + "/"
    os_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
return os_path
```

Now add the above method into your model field which is having attachment 
EX:-

```
atachement = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Attachment')
```

WagtailForm.save()
will save your data.

Comment: Oh! This is just great!
But one last question. How do I implement this field into template form?

Comment: You don't need to do anything in form

Comment: But how to display the form submissions in WagtailAdmin?